# React - getting error when filter array of dates

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

This gives me a array of createdAt timestamps like: ['2022-05-22T21:57:45.202Z', '2022-05-22T21:57:45.205Z']

```
 const unpaid = feeStatus.map((date) => {
    return date.createdAt;
  });
```

Now i wanna try to filter the array and show only those dates that are older than 14 days:

```
unpaid.filter(
    (test) => new Date().getTime() - test.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) > 14
  );
```

But im getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: test.getTime is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `getTime()` function is a method of the `Date` object. So you will need to convert the strings to valid `Date` objects. e.g. `new Date(str)`, or using a library to handle it, like `date-fns`.

Secondly, there is a group of brackets missing from your formula. It should be:

`(new Date().getTime() - new Date(test)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) > 14`.

References:

- Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
- Precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast a string format date to `Date` to be able to use its prototype methods:

```
unpaid.filter(
    (test) => new Date().getTime() - new Date(test).getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) > 14
  );
```